# Js for loop to store values

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

for a project I'm doing with d3.js I need to access a .csv file with multiple values and to be able to know how many rows of the same column have one particular string of text.
Specifically, I have a column that has "Sans" or "Serif" values, and what I tried to do is to create a for loop to get how many rows have those values, but with no result unluckily.
What I tried to do is add this loop in the callback function of the .csv load:

```
    var serif = 0,
    sans = 0;

for (var i = 0; i >= dataset.length; i++) 
    { 
    if (dataset.Grazie = "Sans")
    { return sans += 1; }
    else { return serif += 1; };
    };

    console.log(serif);
    console.log(sans);
```

but in the console the value is still 0.
The column in the dataset is called "Grazie" and the only two values on that column are Sans or Serif. i tried

Any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks!

**EDIT: thanks to Lugia101101 i managed to find the solution, which is:**

```
for (var i = 0; i < dataset.length; i++) {
    if (dataset[i].Grazie == "Sans") { sans ++; }
    else { serif++; }
};
```

Comment: Remove the returns from your code and change the if statement to "dataset[i].Grazie == "Sans". *modified = to == after reading partial answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var serif = 0,
    sans = 0;

for (var i = 0; i <= dataset.length; i++) { 
    if (dataset[i].Grazie == "\"Sans\"") {
        sans++;
    } else {
        serif++;
    }
}

console.log(serif);
console.log(sans);
```

What you were doing was returning a value, which is used to exit out of a function, `return`ing a value. You also need to use a comparator (`==`) instead of assigning a value (`=`).

EDIT: You were also adding semi-colons after a statement. Never add a semi-colon after a curly brace.

EDIT: It seems that another cause for the values equalling 0 would be due to the `for` loop.
Remember to think of it as: set `i` to zero, loop until `i` is not less than or equal to `dataset.length`, incrementing `i` by one every loop.

Comment: this still logs 0 0 in the console, could it be that each value has the quotation mark in the csv? ie "Sans" and "Serif"

Comment: I am not familiar with d3.js, but what does `dataset.Grazie` equal?

Comment: it should access the csv (dataset) column named "Grazie", but since yours and Kyra's reply are so similar I guess I'm doing something else wrong then! I'll try something else to see if I access that column correctly

Just tested that console.log(dataset[0].grazie outputs Sans, so the code to access it should be correct

Comment: Does it return an array? If so add `[i]` to the end of `dataset.Grazie`, that will access the array, also change `dataset.length` to `dataset.Grazie.length`.

Comment: Then what does `dataset[1].Grazie` return?

Comment: it outputs Sans, as the second row has sans in its Grazie column
and if i put i in the brackets it returns error in the console

Comment: It returned only the serif, the sans are still to 0, but to have it I had to remove the square brackets with the i, both from the for and for the console.log, otherwise it returned error! so i can say it's half working now :)

Comment: Add `console.log(i)` before the `if` statement, then tell me what value it gets up to.

Comment: In the csv file, is it `"Serif"` or `Serif`?

Comment: it outputs numbers from 0 to 608, because my dataset is made of 609 rows total

Comment: Change the `if` statement to `"\"Sans\""` then.

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work either :( 
I really don't know what to try know

Comment: with "\"Sans\"" i just get the same results as before

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40868/discussion-between-lugia101101-and-tomtomtom)

Answer (score 0):

When comparing values you have to use `==` rather than `=` (which sets the value of a variable).

`if (dataset.Grazie = "Sans")` should read `if (dataset.Grazie == "Sans")`

As @MarvinSmit pointed out if you want to store incremental values you shouldn't use `return`

Comment: nice catch, totally read over that. But you still need to index the dataset we're itterating over